# Flight connections between south-west Germany and Corsica?

Tags: air-travel, germany, corsica

I've been trying to find flight connections between South-West Germany (Stuttgart, Baden, Strasbourg, Basel) and Corsica (ideally Calvi). There seems to be little choice and many connections are via Paris or Marseille.

Does anyone have experience in this area? I would like to travel between the end of April and mid-June.

Comment: Have you checked [rome2rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Stuttgart/Calvi?dates=2015-4-30/2015-5-16)?

Comment: Maybe nitpicking here, but I feel the urge to point out that neither Strasbourg nor Basel are in South-West Germany. Just in case someone who actually doesn't know stumbles over this question at some point in the future.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - go with your urge by all means. However, the borders are open and there are bridges over the water. From where I live in the Black Forest area of SW Germany, Stuttgart and Strasbourg airports are about 1.5hrs  drive from me. Basel is about 2 hours and Baden about 1hr. I would be silly to ignore the 'foreign' airports. It's what the EU is all about :-)

Comment: @paul: Sure, I live there myself. I just found it strange to read something akin to "cities in Germany (e.g. Strasbourg, Basel)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are non-stop flights between Strasbourg and [Calvi](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A9roport_de_Calvi-Sainte-Catherine) on [HOP](http://www.hop.com/) but only once a week in summer, not in April. There are probably a few other seasonal flights to Corsica from either Strasbourg or Basel/EuroAirport. You haven't mentioned Luxembourg but it is not so far away and Luxair also offers several flights between Corsica and Luxembourg in the summer. None of this is going to help in April, though.

Your best bet outside of the holiday season is EasyJet from Basel. They have non-stop flights to Corsica year-round (probably to Ajaccio, not Calvi). Low cost airline flights typically do not show up on regular travel agents/flight aggregators so you might want to check their website directly.

Alternatively, you might also consider taking the train to Paris and fly from there. It might not seem like a logical choice geographically speaking but there are quick train links with some cities in South-West Germany. The train can be pricey as well so all-in-all it might or might not be more attractive than a flight connection in Paris. There are also night trains from Luxembourg or Strasbourg to Nice or Marseille but then you need to add the price of the ferry or flight to the island as well.

Comment: thanks. I did wonder about the train. I recently travelled to Marseille from Karlsruhe for c €80 each way so that might be an alternative. The air connections I did find were often very expensive especially in the school holidays. e.g. Germanwings Stuttgart-Bastia is around €500pp at Whitsun!

Comment: @paul I still see many return flights for €300-400 in April, which seems reasonable for regular airlines. Cheaper flights are still available on Easyjet. Beyond that it all depends on how long you stay, which exact date your fly, etc. Holiday week-ends are obviously more expensive and if you aren't flexible and are only focused on price it's a very different question.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to book for this year. Volotea from Strasbourg to Bastia for c. 250 Euros return including suitcase, check-in, seat reservation etc. flying in May.